# HTML DOM width + height of visible window

Tags: html, dom, height, width

How do I get the current height and width of the available space in the browser as it is open.

I don't want the height of the total document, just what's visible on the screen.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can take a look at this [blog post](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) to see the method.

and in short in give that code

```
function alertSize() {
    var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
    if(typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
        // Non-IE
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } 
    else if(document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        // IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } 
    else if(document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
        // IE 4 compatible
        myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
    window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
```

also have to be noted that most of js framework (jquery, ext, prototype) would provide a function for doing that (IMHO).

in jQuery:

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

Comment: -1 jQuery doesn't return the height and the width of the visible area, it returns the height and the width the user is able to scroll to.

Comment: It seems to me that with `$(window).width();`,some jQuery users get the full scrollable size, while some jQuery users get the currently visible size.

Comment: I found the problem and a solution: To have `$(window).width();` return the visible area (and not just the same value as `$(document).width();`), make sure to have `<!DOCTYPE html>` (or another proper `DOCTYPE`) included at the very top of your HTML page.

Answer (score 5):

Use the window objects property, inner height/width, to find the dimensions of just the content on the webpage. This includes the scroll bars. Here is a visual explanation -> http://goo.gl/L0cBLA.

Height:

```
window.innerHeight
```

Width:

```
window.innerWidth
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html id="THE_HTML">
<!-- all your stuff... -->
</html>
```

then:

```
document.getElementById('THE_HTML').clientHeight;
```

Tested and working under IE8 and FF3.6...