# JavaScript - Check if absolute coordinates (left, top, right, bottom) are going to be visible on the current viewport

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I have an absolute position for an element that will be created in the future. I want to check if the element is going to be entirely visible on the current viewport. I know I could use `getBoundingClientRect` if the element was rendered on the page, however it's not and it couldn't not be. Is there a way that I can detect if given absolute coordinates (left, top, bottom, right) are going to be visible on the current viewport? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My solution so far - insert an element with `visibility: hidden` and use `getBoundingClientRect`, I was just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Do you know what the absolute coordinates are? Are these numbers you're hard-coding on the page, or are you making an element, putting it on the page, attached to some parent, setting its `position` to `"absolute"` and then trying to figure out what you've got?

Comment: They are dynamically build after a click event. Just assume I'm building a popover that must be shown above a clicked point on the screen, it might be above or bellow the point, depending if it's going to be entirely visible or not. However this is slightly simplified example, just to give you more context.

Comment: Right, but do you know how, say, to get the exact `x` and `y` coordinates of the clicked element, and know the exact width and height of the absolutely-positioned element you're creating, plus know how high you're going to offset the element from what you're clicking on?  If so, see my answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the absolute coordinates of this unrendered element (ie: you can pull them from JS variables, or read them from somewhere, or hard-code them or even write a script to read them out of a `<style>` tag on the page...), then you can do something like this:

```
var viewport = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    width : 0,
    height : 0,
    update : function () {
        this.x = document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        this.y = document.body.scrollTop  || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        this.width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        this.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
};
```

Now you should be able to check for intersections between your element's x,y,width,height against the viewport's x,y,width,height.

Any time the user scrolls, just hit `viewport.update();`.

I will say this:

This method *should* be fairly cross-browser compatible, but I really can't make any guarantees in terms of IE6 -- especially in Quirksmode (no `<!doctype>` on the html file).

Answer (score 0):

Check screen.height and screen.width and compare it to dimensions of the element

Comment: Not going to work.  `window.screen` is the monitor, not the visible page-space inside of the browser.  On the right track, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823700/1060487

```
function alertSize() {
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
  window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
  window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
```